# comments are not showing on godaddy

Tags: php, comments

i am poorly trapped and also not getting any proper support from the Godaddy customer care. I have a comment section which is working perfectly on localhost and some other hosting but it is not working on Godaddy hosting. I don't understand, why this only occurs on godaddy.

Here is my html :

```
<div class="comment-form-container">
        <form id="frm-comment">
            <div class="input-row">
                <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="commentId" placeholder="Name" /> <input class="input-field" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
                <textarea class="input-field" type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Add a Comment">  </textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" class="btn-submit" id="submitButton" value="Publish" /><div id="comment-message">Comments Added Successfully!</div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Here is my script :

```
function postReply(commentId) {
    $('#commentId').val(commentId);
    $("#name").focus();
}

$("#submitButton").click(function () {
    $("#comment-message").css('display', 'none');
    var str = $("#frm-comment").serialize();

    $.ajax({
            url: "comment-add.php",
            data: str,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                //var result = eval('(' + response + ')');
                //var result  = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(response) + ')');
            if (response) {
                $("#comment-message").css('display', 'inline-block');
                $("#name").val("");
                $("#comment").val("");
                $("#commentId").val("");
                listComment();
            } else {
                alert("Failed to add comments !");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
       listComment();
});

function listComment() {
    $.post("comment-list.php",
        function (data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);

            var comments = "";
            var replies = "";
            var item = "";
            var parent = -1;
            var results = new Array();

            var list = $("<ul class='outer-comment'>");
            var item = $("<li>").html(comments);

            for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
            {
                var commentId = data[i]['comment_id'];
                parent = data[i]['parent_comment_id'];

                if (parent == "0")
                {
                    comments = "<div class='comment-row'>"+
                    "<div class='comment-info'><span class='commet-row-label'>from</span> <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + " </span> <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span></div>" + 
                    "<div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>"+
                    "<div><a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + commentId + ")'>Reply</a></div>"+
                    "</div>";

                    var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                    list.append(item);
                    var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                    item.append(reply_list);
                    listReplies(commentId, data, reply_list);
                }
            }
            $("#output").html(list);
    });
}

function listReplies(commentId, data, list) {
    for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
    {
        if (commentId == data[i].parent_comment_id)
        {
            var comments = "<div class='comment-row'>"+
            " <div class='comment-info'><span class='commet-row-label'>from</span> <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + " </span> <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span></div>" + 
            "<div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>"+
            "<div><a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ")'>Reply</a></div>"+
            "</div>";
            var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
            var reply_list = $('<ul>');
            list.append(item);
            item.append(reply_list);
            listReplies(data[i].comment_id, data, reply_list);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am 100% sure that there is no connectivity problem with database. Please help me out.

here is comment-add.php

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$commentId = isset($_POST['comment_id']) ? $_POST['comment_id'] : "";
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : "";
$commentSenderName = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_comment(parent_comment_id,comment,comment_sender_name,date) VALUES ('" . $commentId . "','" . $comment . "','" . $commentSenderName . "','" . $date . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (! $result) {
    $result = mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo $result;
?>
```

here is comment-list.php

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comment ORDER BY parent_comment_id asc, comment_id asc";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$record_set = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($record_set, $row);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($record_set);
?>
```

here is db.php

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx");

?>
```

Comment: There's no PHP code here, just HTML and JavaScript (using the jQuery library).

Comment: can you verify that you have a successful database connection using either `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: i have updated the php, please check now

Comment: yes, i am 100% sure that connection is ok

Comment: Check your error log file. You should find something

Comment: i didn't find any error log file

Comment: sorry, i find it but it is not sowing any error of today